# Can't download terraform module

Tags: terraform, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code, terragrunt

I've the infrastructure of my app defined in terraform/terragrunt.
To be able to deploy the full app in different environments I created a single module with the whole app. However I keep getting:

```
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module xxx: No Terraform configuration files found in directory: .terraform/modules/59ff835a2c7f654267e9f157739ec63a
```

Couldn't really figure out the problem

Answer (score 4):

Terraform will produce this message if the package/directory indicated as `source` does not include any `.tf` files.

One reason this might occur is if the `source` refers to a package (e.g. a repository, or an archive) that actually contains multiple modules in sub-directories, with nothing in the root directory. While [the Standard Module Structure](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html#standard-module-structure) calls for there to be some sort of "default" combining module in the root, with other sub-modules then serving as separated components of that default, that is a convention rather than a requirement and if desired a package can contain *only* modules in sub-directories.

To refer to [a module in a subdirectory](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#modules-in-package-sub-directories), use the special double-slash `//` separator to split the package path from the subdirectory path.

For example, to access [the `modules/consul-cluster` subdirectory](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/consul/aws/0.6.0/submodules/consul-cluster) of [the `hashicorp/consul/aws` module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/consul/aws/0.6.0) in Terraform Registry, your full `source` address would be `hashicorp/consul/aws//modules/consul-cluster`. Similarly, for a subdirectory `vpc` of a git repository source `git::https://example.com/network.git`, you'd set `source` to `git::https://example.com/network.git//vpc`.

Whichever directory you specify must contain at least one `.tf` file for Terraform to consider it to be a valid Terraform module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I kept the multiple directory structure, eg: security/iam and the files inside such directories.
Seems modules don't support this, just a flat directory structure. 
In the end I kept my single module app in a flat directory with a prefix in the files for "namespacing".

Btw, this is an intermediate refactor until I can create more modules for the app.